# Will old coffee in the refrigerator keep for 2 days?

Tags: coffee

I like the acidic taste of old/stale coffee.

I left my coffee at my desk over the weekend, and on Monday morning I took a sip. It tasted good. I did not heat it up, I drank it at room temperature.

But I read it is not advisable to drink coffee left out at room temperature because it is a medium for mold.

If I left it in the refrigerator for 2 days will it be safe to drink?

Comment: Try drinking it chilled, it's much nicer that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If left at room temperature it would certainly become a pool of mold, but if you refrigerate it, especially for just a few days, it should be fine. You would do well to put in a sealed container and probably adding ice to chill it faster would be 'better' but just set in the fridge for 2-3 days (depending on what else is in the fridge) should be ok.

Beyond that, taste is a personal thing and if you like it that way...go for it.

Comment: Cos Callis, FYI, unless maybe you live/work in a very moldy place(?), it would take an awfully long time for coffee to become a "pool of mold". My experience is many days or possibly weeks for even the tiniest dot of mold on the surface of the coffee, especially black coffee.

Comment: A long weekend in a warm office can be enough for strong sweetened black coffee to grow visible mould.

Answer (score 0):

I am drinking a long black with 3 sugars brewed on Monday evening, added 1 teaspoon of sugar extra and reheated in a microwave. It is Saturday morning. It tastes beautiful and I'm not dead yet.

Comment: ...It was kept in the fridge

Comment: Anecdote is not evidence -- just because you did not get dick does not mean it is "safe"!